# Why is this question about testing pdf generation "too broad "

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Any recommendations for how to test generated PDF's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869036/any-recommendations-for-how-to-test-generated-pdfs) has been considered as too broad and i don't understand why. testing generated binaries is really common problem. probably regardless of used technology. there are some techniques to make it easier so it seems to be a perfectly valid question. so: what's wrong with this question?

Comment: How is it *not* too broad?  There's not really any question there at all.  "Tell me everything there is to know about X" is *super* broad.  Like, textbook broad.

Answer (score 4):

Please read the text:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.

Answer (score 2):

It is too broad because it can be answered in too many ways.  You state:

> I'm pinging the community to see if anyone is doing any automated testing on the PDFs they generate

That sounds chatty to me. It makes more sense in an IRC room, or just go out in real life and ak.

StackOverflow is generally tailored for more specific questions. we usually want to see some code, also.

On re-reading, if it was a thorough question with more meat I think it'd fly. But people are biased against short questions like this.